# How to regenerate token in JMeter at fix interval time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am doing API Performance Testing for my application. I am creating a script using JMeter. Now, I am facing the issue that on our application auth_token is only valid for an hour. After that it becomes invalid and we need to generate new token. So how can I manage this mechanism in JMeter where I can regenrate token after fixed interval?

Answer (score 0):

You and create a separate [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) where you will have i.e. [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler configured to "sleep" for 1 hour and the logic to "regenerate" the token.

So you will have 2 Thread Groups:

1. "Normal" one where your API testing happens
2. "Another" one where a new token will be generated each hour

You can pass the token from "Another" to "Normal" thread group using [__setProperty() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I have tried is, I have put token generator and login sampler under once only controller and "main API call" under runtime controller and gave fix amount of time (for eg. half hour). So for half hour main business process will run and after half and hour it will back to cookie generator controller and generate fresh token again and run business process for other 30 mins. And I ran this complete script under one common thread for required time duration. Am I doing right? Please confirm.